# HTML Input onkeypress event is not working as I need

Tags: html, events, input, onkeypress

I've this input in a search modal used to find products by Id or Description in this system I'm working:

```
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" onkeypress="productsDescription(this.value);">
```

And in my javascript I have this function

```
function productsDescription(val) {
    alert(val);
}
```

It happens that when I press a key inside this input, the alert function shows me the value as it was BEFORE the key was pressed. Is there a way to capture the valeu AFTER the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onkeyup` event instead the `onkeypress` happens BEFORE the value gets changed

```
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" onkeyup="productsDescription(this.value);">
```